# Pseudo element visibility behavior

Tags: html, css

I googled a bit, but maybe someone here can explain it to me why do pseudo elements, namely `:before` and `:after`, behave this way.

I have a content div, and inside it there are some elements - paragraphs, anchors, icon, etc. Let's say that on one anchor element I added an `:after` pseudo element and filled it with a content that will show an icon

```
a:after{
    content:"\f001";
    font-family: "Awesome icon font";
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I can toggle the visibility of that element with a click on a button.

The issue is that when that element is hidden, no pseudo element is shown in the DOM. Once I toggle it's visibility (from `display:none;` to, let's say `display: inline-block;`) the pseudo element will be shown.

In a more concrete example I have a nav menu, that can be hidden or shown if I click on a 'hamburger' menu. One nav item is a shopping cart icon. I'm toggling the slide up animation with the click on the menu icon. All the textual menus will slide up nicely, but only when the animation is finished will the shop icon 'pop' into existence. Which looks kinda sloppy.

Why is this happening? Why is the display value, on the container in which the pseudo elements are nested in, controlling the display of the pseudo elements (even though they themselves have a display value that is different from `none`)? Not only does it affect their display value, when you inspect the DOM, if the container has `display: none;` value, there won't be any pseudo element present.

EDIT:

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/at4u56fy/

Comment: Pseudo-elements are inserted INTO the elements, i.e. they are prepended, or appended, to the elements that satisfy the selector. They are not a separate sibling node independent of the elements, and therefore will disappear alongside with the said elements. Try to see pseudoelements as direct descendents, added to the start or the end of the element.

Comment: So basically if I'd like to preserve their visibility I'd have to toggle the `visibility` rule instead of `display`. It was weird because when you have a `display: none;` rule on a div container, and inside are some elements, when you inspect the DOM, they are still there (html code is there, and what's inside them is), but the pseudo elements will completely dissappear. This was kinda confusing to me.

Comment: This last part is more like a problem with the Inspect/Firebug tool. No need to show something that won't be generated because the element has `display: none`. As it may be or not with `:hover` and `:focus`: can't happen in this case

Comment: have you tried 'visibility:hidden'?

Comment: I guess I'll have to use the `visibility` property to avoid this issue.

Comment: Please put your actual question in the title, such as "Pseudo element visibility behavior".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets see what documentation says...

About [`display: none;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display)

> This value causes an element to not appear in the [formatting structure](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#formatting-structure)
>   (i.e., in visual media the element generates no boxes and has no
>   effect on layout). Descendant elements do not generate any boxes
>   either; the element and its content are removed from the formatting
>   structure entirely. This behavior cannot be overridden by setting the
>   'display' property on the descendants.
>
> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box;
>   it creates no box at all. CSS includes mechanisms that enable an
>   element to generate boxes in the formatting structure that affect
>   formatting but are not visible themselves. Please consult the section
>   on [visibility](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#visibility) for details.

Going further to [formatting structure](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#formatting-structure) it says :

> From the annotated document tree, generate a formatting structure.
>   Often, the formatting structure closely resembles the document tree,
>   but it may also differ significantly, notably when authors make use of
>   pseudo-elements and generated content. First, the formatting structure
>   need not be "tree-shaped" at all -- the nature of the structure
>   depends on the implementation. Second, the formatting structure may
>   contain more or less information than the document tree. For instance,
>   if an element in the document tree has a value of 'none' for the
>   'display' property, that element will generate nothing in the
>   formatting structure. A list element, on the other hand, may generate
>   more information in the formatting structure: the list element's
>   content and list style information (e.g., a bullet image).
>
> Note that the CSS user agent does not alter the document tree during
>   this phase. In particular, content generated due to style sheets is
>   not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for reparsing).

So its like if the element is set to `display: none;` user agents seem to ignore CSS generated content. Hence you might want to take a look at `visibility: hidden;` which should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll guess I'll have to find a way to utilize jquery toggle up and down with visibility toggle instead of display toggle.

Comment: @dingo_d toggle the classes instead

Comment: I've had some problems with setting the menu up, since on click I'm showing the menu, and when the menu is not shown you can see the breadcrumbs of the page, and I've finally made it all work nicely, smoothly with jquery. I've had some complications when I tried to create the same effect with css (cannot put the outer container to `overflow: hidden;` because I have drop down menus), and that rules out the `transform: translateY();` css rule.